# GIT Customer Merge Driver Problems(Windows msysgit 1.9.0)

Tags: git, git-merge

In Git we store the data from a database.  A custom .Net application was created to store this data in text files(One for each table).  This worked OK, however as more users joined the team we were getting to many merge conflicts.

To get around this problem I am trying to get a custom Merge Driver developed to replace Git’s inbuilt Merge Driver.  I have tested the application and it works as expected when used from the command line.  However when I integrate this into Git I am getting this error.

```
$ git pull
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: test
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
*PKEY Added[<USR_ID>PRJ8</USR_ID>] - In Both Kept Yours
*OBVDataMerge Mods[1] Ads[0] Dels [0]
error: addinfo_cache failed for path 'FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT'
Auto-merging FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT
FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT: unmerged (d9985c8288b16fb072c314e7aa68401ac5c30491)
FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT: unmerged (f18085d169223241c2f70a12bbdea7dc879d5bbf)
FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT: unmerged (af1e6a12f0d7fab318dba4be5317644595ef8745)
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
```

The lines prefixed with * are just comments my application makes.

After this has completed the “FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT” has been correctly merged(My program worked as expected), however the repository is still in a REBASE state.

This is my Git Configuration File:

```
[merge "OBVData"] 
    name = OBVData Custom Merge
    driver = "DataMergeDriver.exe" %A %O %B
    recursive = binary
```

This is the attributes file on the Directory the data needing to use this merge method.

```
* merge=OBVData
```

My Application will just use the A O and B files to work out how to update the A file.  This A file is then the contents of the FocalPoint/Data/OBV_USERS.TXT after the pull process completes.

I have tried every combination I can think of to fix this problem,  however I am at loss what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe the exit status isn't the one expected by Git to conclude that state? Try to wrap your exe call in a unix shell (or even, just to test, try to replace your exe by a trivial unix script), just to see if the rebase state is better managed in that case. Example of a small script: http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-tricks-tips-workflows/#gitattributes5

Comment: I second this. Windows programmers tend to ignore exit codes completely as the tools they typically use are actively helping them to do so ;-)  So yes, your program should be of type console (I suppose it already is), must not exit until the operation is complete (that is, it must not spawn another executable and quit) and it must return 0 if it successfully resolved the conflict, and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

After a few more hours of testing I found the issue.  The problem was that I was sending Windows line ending vs linux("\r\n" vs "\n").

If the file specified with %A is updated and includes Windows Line endings you will get the above error.

After adding this line of code everything worked as expected.

```
       System.IO.StreamWriter outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outFileName, false);
-->    outFile.NewLine = "\n";**
       foreach (LineItem li in L_Theirs)
       {
             outFile.WriteLine(li.Line);
       }
```

Comment: Good catch. Not related to the status as I initially commented, then. +1